# In Active Directory how do I get the user's computer name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using Powershell, I can get a separate list of all users or all computer on the domain but how can combine both? 
With powershell you can search for users or computers with the following

```
$search= New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
search.Filter  = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"#result=users
```

OR

```
$search= New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
search.Filter  = "("(objectCategory='computers')")"#result=computers
```

How can I combine the two, so i may know what computer a user is assign to?

Comment: How are you "assigning" a user to a computer? Most AD installs will either have a "you can log in anywhere" approach, or a "Members of X group on the machine can log into the machine". If you're using the first, there really isn't a 1 to 1 mapping.

Comment: @TZHX, it make sense the way you explained it, was going about it the wrong way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get that from Active Directory.

Active directory doesn't record which workstation a user logged on from, and unless the user's logonworkstation attribute has been set to limit where they can log on, there's nothing to prevent them from logging on to any and all workstations in the domain.